# Using string array to set data members' values

Tags: c#

I have a class named Person.

Which has data members as follows:

- Boolean Old
- Boolean Educated
- Boolean Employed
- Boolean Married

Now I have a string array 'Values' which contains some of these data members.

My task is to set data members present in an array 'Values' to true for a particular object of class Person.

As in I would be having one array for each of the objects p1,p2,p3... of class Person.

For now I am using 'if' condition for each of the data members to check whether they are present in an array. And setting them to true if they do.
How can I use these string values to set data members to true in more efficient way?

Eg. p1 and p2 are objects of class Person

For p1
Values = {Old, Employed}
In this case I will set p1.Old and p1.Employed to true.

For p2
Values= {Employed,Married}
In this case I will set p2.Employed and p2.Married to true.

```
Person setMembers(string[] Values)
{
    var p1 = new Person();

    string s1 = "Old";
    int i1 = Array.IndexOf(Values, s1);
    string s2 = "Educated";
    int i2 = Array.IndexOf(Values, s2);
    string s3 = "Employed";
    int i3 = Array.IndexOf(Values, s3);
    string s4 = "Married";
    int i4 = Array.IndexOf(Values, s4);

    if (i1 > -1)
    {p1.Old = true;};
    if (i2 > -1)
    {p1.Educated = true;};
    if (i3 > -1)
    {p1.Employed = true;};
    if (i4 > -1)
    {p1.Married = true;};

    return p1;
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what this array contains, and what the result should be? basically: the inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: Best way post your code here .

Comment: @Marc I have edited the Question to give example.

Comment: "I will set p1.Old and p2.Employed to true." Don´t you mean you set p1.Old and p1.Employed to true? You should not set the properties of another instance (in your case p2) from one instance (p1).

Comment: When you say "efficient way" do you mean high performance or easy to add more properties without changing the code way?

Comment: yes sorry, Edited now. Thanks! :)

Comment: "I have edited the Question to give example" -- I don't see anything that looks unequivocally like any example of a string. Please demarcate your string examples unambiguously, so that it is _crystal clear_ what the input looks like.

Comment: @Magnus I was wondering whether there can be a way to parse these string values to set data member's values. So high performance yes.
I am having fix number of data members, about 11. So code won't be changed any way.

Answer (score 2):

One way to optimize conversion of string values to setting properties would be a hash dictionary that maps strings to actions, like this:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<string,Action<Person>> ActionByName =
    new Dictionary<string,Action<Person>>() {
    {"Educated", p => { p.Educated = true; } }
,   {"Employed", p => { p.Employed = true; } }
,   {"Married", p => { p.Married = true; } }
,   {"Old", p => { p.Old = true; } }
};
```

With this dictionary in hand, you could process the values like this:

```
Person p1 = ...
foreach (var val in valuesForP1) {
    Action<Person> a;
    if (ActionByName.TryGetValue(val, out a)) {
        a(p1);
    }
}
```

This way lookup of the thing to do is performed using hash table. Note that you can skip the dictionary and use `switch` instead, like this:

```
foreach (var val in valuesForP1) {
    switch(val) {
        case "Educated": p1.Educated = true; break;
        case "Employed": p1.Employed = true; break;
        case "Married": p1.Married = true; break;
        case "Old": p1.Old = true; break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps even initialize the static dictionary using reflection.

Comment: Nice and elegant way with actions in addition with TryGetValue-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `System.Linq`, then you would have `Contains` function and then you  can do something like this

```
objPerson.Old = Values.Contains("Old");
objPerson.Educated = Values.Contains("Educated");
```

Comment: In this case I would have to write if condition for each data member and that is what I am doing right now.
I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: No you don't need if condition. `Contains` returns the `boolean` value which you can set directly.

Answer (score 1):

With reflection... but the string values have to match exactly the property names

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testPerson = CreatePerson(new[] { "Old", "Employed" });
        Console.WriteLine(testPerson.Old);
        Console.WriteLine(testPerson.Educated);
        Console.WriteLine(testPerson.Employed);
        Console.WriteLine(testPerson.Married);
    }

    public static Person CreatePerson(string[] args)
    {
        Person result = new Person();
        Type personType = typeof(Person);
        foreach (string item in args)
        {
            personType.GetProperty(item).SetMethod.Invoke(result, new object[] { true });
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public bool Old { get; set; }
    public bool Educated { get; set; }
    public bool Employed { get; set; }
    public bool Married { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may write a method that sets your properties accordingly:

```
class Person {
    bool old, educated, employed, married;

    void SetValues(string[] values) {
        this.old = values.Contains("Old");
        this.educated = values.Contains("Educated");
        this.employed = values.Contains("Employed");
        this.married = values.Contains("Married");
    }
```

Now you may call this as follows:

```
Person p1 = new Person();
p.SetValues(new[] { "Old", "Married" };
```

Comment: In this case won't I would be doing the same as to write 'if' condition to check for each data member?

Comment: You always have to check if your desired value is within the array, no matter if you´re using an explicit if-statement for this, a LINQ-query or (as in my case) the contains-method, so ofc. it is kind of if-statement.